# Linux - Any way to limit disk usage on a per directory level?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I know I can use `quota` to limit the amount of disk space per user. However I'm wondering if there's some way in Linux to limit the disk usage of a directory? Ideally I'd like something like

```
limit_space -n 100M ./path/to/directory
```

And any attempts to create a file or write to a file that would make it more than 100MB would fail with a similar error as if you tried to write to a full disk.

I know it gets complicated because of symlinks and hardlinks and block sizes and stuff.

The reason I'm asking is that I have a programme that downloads files to a temporary directory, and I want to test that that it does the right thing if it can't write the file. Simulating a full disk would be one of the ways. If there's a quick one-liner like this, then I can test this easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is just for testing purposes, I suggest you create a [smallish loopback filesystem](http://www.walkernews.net/2007/07/01/create-linux-loopback-file-system-on-disk-file/) and mount it at the place you want test full disks.

Comment: Good call. Loopback filesystems are underappreciated for learning, experimenting and testing.

Answer (score 3):

You can crate separate partition for this directory. If You don't want repartitioning your hard drive you can crate virtual partition with loop device (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device).

//edit:
this topic may interest You: https://superuser.com/questions/82025/linux-how-to-create-a-folder-that-behaves-like-a-file/)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using lvm for flexibility in having several virtual volumes (with the added bonus of hot backups, etc)?

(loopback filesystems are limited in number)